# If $u$ is a Sobolev function then $\nabla u = 0$ on $\{ u = c\}$.

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

There is a result of the form:

> If $u$ is a Sobolev function on some domain then $\nabla u = 0$ on $\{ x \mid u(x) = c\}$ where $c$ is constant.

Can someone point me to a specific reference? I cannot find it anywhere. I want to know the precise assumptions on the domain.

Comment: This is false, even for smooth functions with compact support.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am certainly missing some assumptions/restrictions. There is definitely some result of this form.

Comment: Something's missing here in addition to assumptions on the _domain_! Look. Say it happens that $u(x,y)=x$ on some open set. So in that open set $u=c$ is the same as $x=c$. We have $u_x=1$ everywhere in that open set, including on the set $u=c$. (Maybe $c$ was supposed to be the maximum value of $u$?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, that is why I said I am not sure exactly what it is. Anyhow I found the answer (see below).

Comment: Ah, almost everywhere, that's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Evans and Gariepy's [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Measure_Theory_and_Fine_Properties_of_Fu.html?id=HZONacVPGlMC), page 130, Theorem 4 (iv), is the result you want. Remember "a.e." is the key element here.

Answer (score 0):

The result is:

> If $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ on an open set $\Omega$, and if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a null set, then $\nabla u = 0$ a.e. on $u^{-1}(A)$.

The result is due to Stampacchia. If anyone can refer me to an English proof I'd be grateful.

My source is Nonlinear Analysis by Gasinski and Papageorgiou ([Remark 2.4.26](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HYkL4XM66jEC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=stampacchia+null+set&source=bl&ots=_4G5G1iMT1&sig=OhLC388NnEpR3EAFtdCIAT6_ym8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7dWiVePMD8vxUr-chIAJ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=stampacchia%20null%20set&f=false)).